# Forward Messages from two Kafka Clusters to Another

Tags: apache-kafka

I have three Kafka clusters: A, B, and C. I have data incoming on Cluster A on topic incoming.dataA and Cluster B on topic incoming.dataB

I need a way to send all messages received on incoming.dataA on Cluster A and incoming.dataB on Cluster B to a topic on Cluster C, received.data. Can this be done?

I am aware of mirroring and streaming but neither of those help when forwarding data from kafka cluster to another (when their topic names differ).

Answer (score 1):

MirrorMaker can only be used between two clusters, so you'd have to chain A->B->C

Your next option would be to use some Apache projects (or just regular client app) such as Spark/Flink/Beam/Nifi/Camel to consume from each cluster with individually configured consumers, and somehow forward records with a single producer client (would be recommended to join the data first, somehow, assuming order or some characteristics matter)